# Como desenhar uma Ribbon(laço de presente ou etiqueta) em uma div?

Tags: html, css

Como faço para desenhar esse laço(ribbon) verde no canto superior direito da div central?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consegui encontrar uma maneira de faze-lo, alguém poderia me ajudar nisso? Depois da resposta eu posso editar a pergunta para que fique menos centralizada para o meu caso.

```css
.box{
  background-color:red;
}
.box p{
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
}
.box > input{
  margin-left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>R$ 180,00</p>
  <p>1 mês</p>
  <input type="radio">5
<div>
```

Comment: Jovem preferi remover a resposta por enquanto agora que ficou mais claro o que vc quer. Logo tento te responder com uma opção e edito a resposta que removi

Comment: tranquilo, valeu...

Comment: Ok resposta restaurada depois da uma olhada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Só para constar, este tipo de efeito normalmente é chamado de **"ribbon"**, pois lembra um laço de presente, de caixa ou de uso semelhante

Não bastará apenas rotacionar um DIV, teremos que "aparar ele", ou seja, teremos que criar um elemento principal, só usar `::before` e `::after` não vai funcionar.

Para rotacionar usaremos

```
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

Para evitar que o ribbon afete os outros elementos iremos usar quando for clicar ou selecionar algum texto ou elemento, pois o elemento principal acaba ficando maior que o ribbon, mesmo que não possa "enxerga-lo":

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Restaura os eventos no conteúdo do ribbon

```
pointer-events: auto;
```

E o "principal", para aparar o ribbon usaremos:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

O elemento vai ter que ser algo como:

```
<div class="seu-elemento">
    <div class="ribbon">
        <div class="ribbon-content">Novo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note que o `seu-elemento` se refere ao elemento que deseja aplicar, ele precisa receber:

```
position: relative;
```

O efeito deve ficar assim:

> **Nota:** desta forma funciona até mesmo no **Internet Explorer 9**

```css
.ribbon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none; /* impede que o ribbon atrapalhe outros elementos*/
}

.ribbon > .ribbon-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 150%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    pointer-events: auto; /* restaura os eventos somente para o conteudo */
}


/* efeitos somente para teste*/
body {
    background: #cfcfcf;
}

.seu-elemento {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="seu-elemento">
    <div class="ribbon">
        <div class="ribbon-content">Novo</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seu-elemento">
    <div class="ribbon">
        <div class="ribbon-content">Novo</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seu-elemento">
    <div class="ribbon">
        <div class="ribbon-content">Novo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode usar pseudo-elementos `::before` e :`:after` para isso.

No `::before` vc usa um `linear-gradiente` em `45deg`, e no `::after` vc coloca o `content:"novo"`

Veja como fica no exemplo:

```css
.container {
 width: 190px;
 height: 160px;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.container::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, green 50%, green 75%, transparent 75%);
}
.container::after {
 content: "novo";
 position: absolute;
 top: -10px;
 right: -10px;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 color: #fff;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.box{
 background-color:#999;
  float:left;
}
.box p{
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
}
.box > input{
 margin-left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container box">
  <p>R$ 180,00</p>
  <p>1 mês</p>
  <input type="radio">5
</div>
<div class="container box">
  <p>R$ 180,00</p>
  <p>1 mês</p>
  <input type="radio">5
</div>
<div class="container box">
  <p>R$ 180,00</p>
  <p>1 mês</p>
  <input type="radio">5
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
  background-color: #C7C7C7;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.etiqueta{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: -30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

.box p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <p>R$ 310,00</p>
    <p>1 mês</p>
    <input type="radio">5
    
    <div class="etiqueta">Novo</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p>R$ 270,00</p>
    <p>1 mês</p>
    <input type="radio">5
    
    <div class="etiqueta">Novo</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p>R$ 2900,00</p>
    <p>1 ano</p>
    <input type="radio">5
    
    <div class="etiqueta">Novo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```